# Insert a picture to avoid the empty space

Tags: graphics

I use

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.92\textwidth]{280}
  \caption{Page 280 }
\end{figure}

$\left.\right.$\\
At node H there is a $30\%$ chance that the employee will choose to exercise the option.\\
In cases where the employee does not choose to exercise, there is a $45\%$ chance that the employee leaves the company and has to exercise.\\
The total probability of exercise is
$$0.3 + (1- 0.3)\times 0.05 = 0.334.$$
```

Even I manually modify the edition, when I insert some new sentences in the content, the problem will occur and I need modification again. So is there any intelligent way to insert the picture.

If I use

```
Here $\E^T$ is under $T$-forward measure. As the margin paid everyday, there is no time value, then we can regard as $r=0$  or a stock with dividend yield $q = r.$ in the futures price.

\vspace{10pt}
\textbf{Speculating} The observation that in the classical Black-Scholes theory the drift of the asset plays no part.
```

the result is

[image]
But my goal is following. And I only want to indent for this paragraph, but not change the whole article style. And `\indent` seems not work for the beginning of a paragraph.

[image]

Comment: You already have found the intelligent way. LaTeX places the images for you so the page can be filled with text. Once you have more text, you will see the advantage.

Comment: The experience will be even better avoiding the `h` option and adding `\label{key}` inside the caption and ` (fig. \ref{key }`) in the text (do not forget compile twice).

Comment: @Johannes_B But the later text will set after the figure but not fill up the empty space in the  old paper. Pls see the update

Comment: @Fran sorry could you show some detail?

Comment: `$\left.\right.$\\ ` What the heck? What is that supposed to be doing? Stuff like that messes up your document, it isn't LaTeX, it is you. Same for the displayed math later. I suggest to stop right now and read an introduction.

Comment: @A.Oreo it could be that your image have already a lot of the empty space (check it with  `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.92\textwidth]{280}}`), or lack of text, your options, paragraph skips, all together, ...who know without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to check. Also see this [famous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) to understand the floats environments.

Comment: @Johannes_B  I want to left some space between the old paragraph and new paragraph, moreover, I don't want place some space at the beginning of the new paragraph(it seems not allowed to use `xxxx   \vspace{10pt}\\ xxxxx`). Then I use this way

Comment: You aren't using paragraphs (blank line in the input) right now. This messes everything up. You really should read an introduction ([LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) <- free ebook) and then start over.

Comment: you should clearly remove the \left\right weirdness, but for the main question it is very hard to tell as you have not posted any usable code but it looks like the figure would not fit on that page, so it has gone to the next, what else would you want it to do? If you write more text the space at the bottom of the first page will fill up. Note you should almost never have `\\ ` outside tables, let latex do the line breaking it is rare to need forced line breaks in text. Also `$$` should not be used in latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah I know this sentence is not acceptable. But how to obtain the goal such like `xxxx (next line)\vspace{10pt}\\(next line) xxxxx). ` i.e `left some space between the old paragraph and new paragraph, moreover, I don't want place some space at the beginning of the new paragraph`

Comment: why would you want to have `\\ ` after a `vspace` ? what would you want it to do?  and your `ie .. old and new paragraph`  is hard to understand as `xxxx (next line)\vspace{10pt}\\(next line) xxxxx` is a single paragraph.  Just use blank lines between paragraphs the choice of inter paragraph spacing and whether you use an indent is set by the document class or in the preamble (eg parskip package)  in the very rare cases that you need to add extra space between two paragraphs use a blank line to end the first the use `\vspace{10pt}` to add additional space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  pls see the update

Comment: USE PACKAGE `parskip`. (Sorry for yelling!)

Comment: you should almost never need explicit spaces such as `\vspace` or font changes  such as `\textbf`  the choice of spacing is a document-wide style choice which should be set once at the start of the document. you **Speculating** looks like some kind of inline heading so should probably be `\paragraph{Speculating}` which would add additional vertical space, make it bold and have no indentation with **no** additional markup.

Comment: `And \indent seems not work for the beginning of a paragraph.` you seen to want `\noindent` rather than `\indent` don't you? (But you do not need either)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot, `\paragraph` is exactly what I want.